# How can I aggregate 1kmx1km cells into ones of 50km by 50km in Arc Map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a map with cells on 1 square kilometer and need to aggregate them in 50 by 50 kms.

I have tried Aggregate polygons and Aggregate and have not been successful.

Comment: Is there important data to be 'saved' on these cells? Create a fishnet of 50km by 50km, intersect (spatial join) then dissolve by the fishnet ID - existing attributes can be merged by min/max/sum/mean.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I recommend trying any suggestions posted as comments here, then if you are still stuck, use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with precisely what you have tried - always include any error messages (as text).

Comment: Are these cells Vector (polygon) or Raster? If the cells are raster cells use the answer by Brad or Resample the raster... the tools Aggregate polygons and Aggregate are vector tools but when faced with a whole mesh will try to dissolve all touching cells into a single polygon.

Answer (score 2):

**General** - use the export data and change the cell size in the dialog.
[image: export]
[image: export2]

**For more detailed output** - Or you could use the georferencing toolbar, make a slight adjustment and then the rectify tool becomes available.

[image: export3]

That is the only way I know how to get the rectify tool which does then allow you to select the resample type. (probably another way to do that)

[image: export4]